# how to access apollo client error object properties

Tags: javascript, apollo-client

I'm fetching a query to a GraphQL server that throws an error if something goes wrong. Now, I want to have access to that error but instead Apollo Client is showing me the general `Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 500`.
By adding the onError property to my query, I can see the Error object in the console but only if it's wrapped in {}, otherwise it's just text.

This is my code:

```
  const { data, loadMore, loading, error, retry } = useRetryableQuery<
    GetDevices,
    DevicesQueryVariables
  >(devicesQueries.GetDevices, {
    onError: (networkError) => {
      console.log(networkError); //this will show me the error as a whole text and not an object
      console.log({ networkError }) // this will show me an object which its properties I cannot access
    },
    errorPolicy: "all",
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    paginationPath: ["paging"],
    itemsPaths: [["filteredDevices", "rows"]],
    variables: {
      ...queryVariables,
      connectionPaging: {
        offset: 0,
        limit: PAGE_SIZE,
      },
    },
  });
```

How can I access the properties nested inside the networkError object?

First screenshot is without {}
Second one is with {}

[image: Error without wrapping in {}]

[image: Error after wrapping it in {}]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to this Apollo Client issue: [useQuery() refetch throws on error instead of flowing through hook](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3571), so getting the error from the ApolloProvider directly allowed me to access the error sent from the backend:

```
const errorLink = useMemo(
() =>
  onError((error) => {
    const message = getApolloError({ graphQLErrors: error.graphQLErrors 
 });
    if (message) {
      localStorage.setItem("error", message);
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem("error");
    }
    if (message === "Session expired.") {
      logout(true);
    }
  }),
 [logout]
);

const client = useMemo(
 () =>
   new ApolloClient({
     cache,
     link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, authLink, httpLink]),
     defaultOptions: {
       watchQuery: {
         fetchPolicy: "network-only",
       },
       query: {
         fetchPolicy: "network-only",
       },
     },
   }),
 [httpLink, errorLink]
);
```